# How to use Pywikibot to download only a few selected pages?

Tags: mediawiki, bots

How to use [Pywikibot](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikibot) to extract only a single page or a few pages along with the revision histories from a MediaWiki wiki, instead of the whole wiki?

Answer (score 2):

Are you dead set on using pywikibot? I'm biased because I help develop it, but I'd use [dumpgenerator.py](https://github.com/WikiTeam/wikiteam/blob/master/dumpgenerator.py), but you need to alter the list of titles manually.

There is a [feature request](https://github.com/WikiTeam/wikiteam/issues/29) for a comment line argument though, it was asked before.